# How to drop a RANGE partition?

Tags: database, time-series, partition, dolphindb

Known that the function `dropPartition` requires parameters like this:

```
dropPartition(dbHandle, partitionPaths, [tableName])
```

How to specify the parameter `partitionPaths` if I want to drop several range partitions with one call of the function? I can only drop one partition once in this way:

```
db=database(dbPath, RANGE,  0 5 10 15 20)       

t=table(rand(20, 100) as ID,rand(1.0, 100) as x)

pt = db.createPartitionedTable(t, `tb1, `ID)

pt.append!(t)

dropPartition(db,"0_5")
```

Answer (score 0):

To drop multiple partitions in one call, please put partition paths in array.

```
dropPartition(db,["/0_5", "/10_15"])
```